# ComboBox as a children in inkcanvas

Tags: wpf

I want that when I click in a specific zone of the inkCanvas a comboBox appear at a specific zone in that inkcanvas. I select an item of the comboBox and the comboBox disapear.
With coding I can add a comboBox as a children in the inkcanvas but the comboBox is like an image and cannot be selected. 
Here is my code :

```
ComboBox moncombo = new ComboBox();
InkCanvas.SetTop(moncombo , 285);
InkCanvas.SetLeft(moncombo , 570);
InkEditor.Children.Add(moncombo );
```

Any idea to have a functionnal comboBox?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `InkCanvas` avoid interacting with children `Controls`. But you can add a transparent `Canvas` on top of the `InkCanvas`, and add you `ComboBox` there:

```
<Grid>
    <InkCanvas/>
    <Canvas>
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's works fine in design mode, but I want to be able to do the same at runtime. I also use a scrollbar for the inkCanvas control.

Comment: You can wrap the `Grid` in a `ScrollViewer`. And everything is working fine at runtime (I am not even showing the Design window here...)